# Uniform convergence of a series on $[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am stuck with this problem. I  am trying to check the uniform convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{-2x(1+x)^{n-1}}{[1+(1+x)^{n-1}][1+(1+x)^n]}$$

on the interval $[-1,1]$ and $[0,1]$.

The first thing I could think was to of course put $t= 1+x$. I thought resolving into partial fractions would be the next step. But that is not proving to be useful the way I have done. Am I doing this correct or should I adopt another approach.

P.S. This is not a homework problem. I am just trying some problems on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$[1+(1+x)^n]-[1+(1+x)^{n-1}]=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x-1)$$

**Reference** : [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(1+x)^{n-1}(1-(1+x))$?

Comment: @DanZimm, Thanks.Rectified

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very helpful. That would give a partial sum of $s_n = \dfrac{(1-t^n)}{(1+t^n)}$ and I can proceed from there.

Comment: I don't get the hint, which has a minus sign on the LHS whereas the original question's denominator is a product...

Comment: Oh, partial fractions...? Right +1

Comment: @Vishesh, My pleasure. Nice to hear that. Unique name, too.